# Ошибка pymysql.err.IntegrityError

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Пытаюсь сделать insert новостей в бд.И чтобы повторные новости не добавлялись.Есть такой метод проверку url новости:

```
# < Проверка новости на наличие в БД.
    def check_exist_link(self, resource_link):
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT `link` FROM items WHERE `link` = "'+resource_link+'"')
        exists_links = self.cursor.fetchall()
        # < Проверка на наличие новости в БД.
        if len(exists_links) == 0:
            # < Если вернет false значит новости в бд нету.
            return False
        else:
            # < Если вернет true значит новость в бд есть.
            return True
```

Но что-то этот метод работает не корректно. Перед insert у меня стоит  такое условие:

```
if exist_link is not True:
    huge_insert = parser.huge_insert_db(query)
```

Вот собственно сам traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:PycharmProjects/oop_parser/main_parser.py", line 59, in <module>
    huge_insert = parser.huge_insert_db(query)
  File "C:PycharmProjects\oop_parser\boilerpipe_parser_component.py", line 132, in huge_insert_db
    self.cursor.execute(query)
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "C:Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "C:Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "C:Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "C:Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'http://bryansk-news.net/incident/2019/10/08/37541.html' for key 'link'")

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Что я делаю не так ? С чего стоит начать копать ?

**UPD:** Эврика ! Я понял в чем ошибка.На этом ресурсе который [парсится](http://bryansk-news.net).Есть новости которые повторяются.Решение это в методе:`get_resource_links` сделать проверку на повторяющиеся ссылки.

```
def get_resource_links(self, resource_page , link_rule, resource_domain):
        resource_links = []
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resource_page, 'lxml')
        resource_links_blocks = soup.findAll(link_rule[0], {link_rule[1]: link_rule[2]})
        for resource_link_block in resource_links_blocks:
            a_tag = resource_link_block.find('a')
            if a_tag:
                link = a_tag.get('href')
                if resource_domain not in link:
                    resource_links.append(resource_domain + link)
                else:
                    resource_links.append(link)
        return resource_links
```

Теперь встал вопрос,как это можно реализовать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эврика ! Я понял в чем ошибка.На этом ресурсе который парсится.Есть новости которые повторяются.Решение это в методе:get_resource_links сделать проверку на повторяющиеся ссылки.

```
def get_resource_links(self, resource_page , link_rule, resource_domain):
        resource_links = []
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resource_page, 'lxml')
        resource_links_blocks = soup.findAll(link_rule[0], {link_rule[1]: link_rule[2]})
        for resource_link_block in resource_links_blocks:
            a_tag = resource_link_block.find('a')
            if a_tag:
                link = a_tag.get('href')
                if resource_domain not in link:
                    resource_links.append(resource_domain + link)
                else:
                    resource_links.append(link)
        # < Отсеивание ссылок на уникальные.
        resources_links = unique(resource_links)
        return resources_links
```

В итоге все работает.

Огромная благодарность  [пользователю gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201445/gil9red)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `INSERT INTO ...` используйте `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` тогда дубликаты не будут добавляться и не будет той ошибки.

[Например](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853634/5909792), был запрос:

```
INSERT INTO users_partners (uid,pid) VALUES (1,1);
```

А станет:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO users_partners (uid,pid) VALUES (1,1);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ,но я думаю такой вариант.Может плохо сказаться на производительности.

Comment: @Raharasomaha, это часть движка базы данных и стопудов будет быстрее работать чем реализация через отдельный запрос SELECT из скрипта

Comment: А еще один момент,я заметил что при `insert ignore` выходят предупреждения об ошибке дубликата.

Comment: @Raharasomaha, а скиньте текст либо сами поищите как их глушить через pymysql :)

Comment: Не сочтите за наглость и грубость,но я лучше попытаюсь понять почему у меня выходит эта ошибка.Если по сути дела у меня стоит метод на проверку дубликата ) А и еще огромная благодарность то что потратили на меня ваше время !)

Comment: @Raharasomaha, нет проблем :) По логике текущего вашего кода должно работать, но непонятно откуда заполняется `exist_link` -- может такое быть, что вы его после `exist_link = self.check_exist_link(link)` как-то изменили? Я бы еще раз проверил результат `def check_exist_link(self, resource_link):`, а конкретно `exists_links` для существующих и нет ссылок. Кст, `if len(exists_links) == 0:` можно заменить на `if not exists_links:`, а `if exist_link is not True:` на `if not exist_link:`

Comment: Как вы посоветовали я проверил еще раз `exists_links`.Но перед проверкой отчистил таблицу `items` и все нормально.После запустил код и решил сделать insert.Код опять обвалился,но записал одну новость.Потом опять проверил результат в итоге такой: `(('http://bryansk-news.net/society/2019/10/08/37556.html',),)` `()`
`()`

Comment: @Raharasomaha, понятнее не стало... попробуйте вместо `fetchall` использовать `fetchone` и возвращать `1` (пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a0fc6877ab058b59110757758e5eba28e170c58e/Check%20with%20notification/games_with_denuvo/common.py#L157). Странно, что код обвалился на insert для пустой таблице. Нужно поиграться с тем запросом для поиска дубликатов -- сделайте отдельный скрипт и гоняйте в нем huge_insert_db и check_exist_link, т.к. если у вас вернулся кортеж с пустыми кортежами, то для проверки это `True` -- элементы в кортеже ведь есть, а по логике это False

Comment: *Странно, что код обвалился на insert для пустой таблице* Он обваливается на пустую таблицу потому-что тот ресурс с которого я парсю новости.Имеет повторные новости.

Comment: @Raharasomaha, если имеет повторные новости, но при добавлении в базу таблица явно не будет пустой. Не, это все болталогия :) Заполните вашу таблицу и тестируйте работу только `check_exist_link` пока без вставок. Убедитесь что для новых записей вернется `False`, а для существующих `True`. Нужно убедиться что это правильно работает. Разберетесь с этим и не будет проблем с вставкой

Comment: Дело в том что метод `check_exit_link` работал нормально.Но потом что-то перестал работать нормально.Но хорошо я последую вашему совету.

Comment: Проверил `check_exist_link` метод работает как часы.Думаю проблема в другом.

Comment: Я добавил UPD в вопрос.Не могли бы вы его еще раз взглянуть на вопрос  ?

Comment: @Raharasomaha, это не поможет если при последующем вызове снова получите дубликаты, кст не нашел в get_resource_links проверку на дубликаты. Раз check_exist_link работает правильно, то одна причина проблемы -- вызов `huge_insert = parser.huge_insert_db(query)` без той проверки. Кст, вот вы составляете `query`, я так понимаю там находится sql-запрос? Может ли быть, что в `query` имеет ссылку, что `check_exist_link` *не проверил*? А так... лучше используйте `INSERT IGNORE INTO ` и уберите ваши проверки ссылок -- так меньше кода будет, безопаснее. А проблема логирования ошибок... думаю решаемая

Comment: Я и говорю дело все в том что методе `get_resource_links` нету проверки ссылок на дубликаты.И из-за этого выходит ошибка `PYMYSQL`.Мне надо всего сделать проверку ссылок на дубликаты

Comment: @Raharasomaha, запустили вы вот get_resource_links отсеили дубликаты внутри метода. Через несколько дней запустили снова get_resource_links  отсеил дубликаты, но при добавлении в базу эти новости уже были. Как скрипт себя поведет? `check_exist_link` обнаружит дубликаты в базе и `parser.huge_insert_db` не будет вызван. Кст, я зря не попросил вас показать код `parser.huge_insert_db` и что должно быть в `query`. У вас, случаем, в `query` не передается список ссылок, а среди них и дубликаты? Оо

Comment: Нет в `query` у меня передается insert запрос и все.